# how to call a Google API

Tags: google-api, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I read the following two pages on Google:
1) https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#getting_a_list_of_documents_and_files
and
2) https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

I can go as far as getting an access_token (OAuth2) to be used in a subsequent Google API call (I want to call Google Docs Listing or Google Drive).

I wanted to use curl or something similar and just form my https URL.
- As such in the 1st document states to form a URL as follows:
https: //docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full
- In the 2nd document, the example states to use something like https: //www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=xxxxx
(adding the access token to the call)

Several questions
- Do I call googleapis.com or docs.google.com?
- can I call https: //docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full?access_token=xxxxx 
  just add the access token to the call?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need some effort to approach a Google API the first time, but then it's easy and elegant:

1. **Manual preparation** (*One-time action*): Sign in to Google, create a project, enable the API in question, create new Cient ID.
2. **Get OAuth code, refresh token and access token** (*one-time action*).
3. **Make the API call** (*repetitive arbitrary actions*).

Here is a detailed explanation of the entire process - [Steps to make a Google API call](http://www.milevis.com/Tips/Details/52).
A practical sample based on the Google Calendar API with full demo code in a single HTML file can also be reviewed here - [Easy and compact access to my Google calendars](http://www.milevis.com/Tips/Details/55).

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to get started is probably the quickstart guide for the Google Drive API, which shows how to setup your environment and write a complete command-line app to upload a file to Drive:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

Hie you can go through the Google Docs Sample Available [Here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/?repo=samples&r=43b27a71a63db8a8c481a6f3e95ffa9533e01865)

it's a command line smaple but this same thing you can implement in android. it works for me. you will find "docs-cmdline-sample" in repo. that will help you.

Comment: Thanks, the sample code makes use of language specific libraries which do not show me how/where the access token should be used while actually invoking the Google API.